# Summary data in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I am a newbie in sql coding. I would like to make summary in Oracle Database 
But I did not find it how to do that. I just make query like this ;

```
SELECT 
    T1.LINE_CD  
  , T1.ITM_CD
  , T1.INST_NO
  , T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT1
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT2
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT3
  , NVL(SUM(T3.PROD_RESULT),0) AS TOTAL_PRODUCTION
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT1
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT2
  , NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT3
  , NVL(SUM(T3.TF_FG),0) AS TOTAL_TRANSFER

FROM TMCI_IM_PROD T1 INNER JOIN CM_HINMO_ALL T2
ON T1.ITM_CD=T2.ITM_CD
LEFT JOIN
TMCI_IM_PROD T3
ON T1.INST_NO=T3.INST_NO
WHERE 0=0 AND
T1.INST_NO = 'M181101666' AND
T1.INS_TS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND
T3.INS_TS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS')

GROUP BY 
    T1.ITM_CD, 
    T1.INST_NO,
    T1.SHIFT,
    T1.PROD_RESULT,
    T1.LINE_CD, 
    T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY, 
    T1.TF_FG,
    T1.INS_TS
ORDER BY T1.INS_TS ASC
```

And the result of this query would be like this picture;
[image]
Does anyone here could help me to find the ways how to make it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not post Images for sample data and expected output. You should add only textual data in tabular form, so that it's easier for others  to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to respond without seeing without seeing the structure of your tables, however here are a few assumptions :

- several output fields are built from `NVL/DECODE` on the same field(s). This  defeats the aggregation and can possibly generate duplicates. Either remove that logic, or copy the `NVL/DECODE` to the `GROUP BY` clause
- You have a filter on a field that you do not display, and you seem to expect a single row anyway ; remove that useless level of aggregation

Here is a query that implements the above principles :

```
SELECT 
    T1.LINE_CD,  
    T1.ITM_CD,
    T1.INST_NO,
    T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT1,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT1,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT2,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)AS PROD_SHIFT3,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT1,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT2,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.TF_FG),0)AS TRANS_SHIFT3,
    NVL(SUM(T1.PROD_RESULT),0) AS TOTAL_PRODUCTION,
    NVL(SUM(T1.TF_FG),0) AS TOTAL_TRANSFER
FROM TMCI_IM_PROD T1 
    INNER JOIN CM_HINMO_ALL T2 ON T1.ITM_CD=T2.ITM_CD
WHERE 
    T1.INST_NO = 'M181101666' AND
    T1.INS_TS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY 
    T1.LINE_CD,
    T1.ITM_CD, 
    T1.INST_NO, 
    T1.SHIFT,
    T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY,
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.PROD_RESULT),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.PROD_RESULT),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.TF_FG),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.TF_FG),0),
    NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.TF_FG),0)
```

Comment: Thank you in advance. I have tried it, but it did not work. The query result would appear error message like this. ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 0):

You have to rework your query a bit in order to group your result. Any non unique column must be inside a group function.

1. Use group function around any column where you want summarized values
2. Exclude any column inside your group function from de group by clause

and then try it again:

```
SELECT 
  T1.LINE_CD  
, T1.ITM_CD
, T1.INST_NO
, T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)) AS PROD_SHIFT1
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)) AS PROD_SHIFT2
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.PROD_RESULT),0)) AS PROD_SHIFT3
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,1,T1.TF_FG),0)) AS TRANS_SHIFT1
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,2,T1.TF_FG),0)) AS TRANS_SHIFT2
, SUM(NVL(DECODE(T1.SHIFT,3,T1.TF_FG),0)) AS TRANS_SHIFT3
, SUM(NVL(T1.PROD_RESULT,0)) AS TOTAL_PRODUCTION
, SUM(NVL(T1.TF_FG,0)) AS TOTAL_TRANSFER
FROM TMCI_IM_PROD T1 
INNER JOIN CM_HINMO_ALL T2
ON T1.ITM_CD=T2.ITM_CD
WHERE 0=0 AND
T1.INST_NO = 'M181101666' AND
T1.INS_TS BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY 
T1.ITM_CD, T1.INST_NO, T1.LINE_CD, PROD_SCHD_QTY, T1.INS_TS
ORDER BY T1.INS_TS ASC
```

Comment: Thank you in advance. I have tried too but it still the same